# change the second datepickers minDate when selecting date from another datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I' m using jquery ui datepicker.

I have two datepicker on the page, from and to datepickers

when i select a date in one datepicker i update the max and min date to the second datepicker.

my problem is that just before it close(hide) the seleted datepicker,
it show the second datepicker instead of the first one (just when i update the min date of the second datepicker) and then close it.

why does it show the second datepicker when i update the min date from the other datepicker?

how can i hide the datepicker before i update the second datepicker?

```
 <!doctype html>
<html >
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<input name="fromDateCalendar" type="text" value="10/12/2013" id="fromDateCalendar" style="width:100px;" />     

 <input name="toDateCalendar" type="text" value="09/01/2014" id="toDateCalendar" style="width:100px;" />    

<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#fromDateCalendar').datepicker({
            onSelect: function (date) {change1(date);}});

        $("#toDateCalendar").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (date) {change2(date);}, maxDate: '0' });
    });

    function change1(date) {
        $('#toDateCalendar').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);}

    function change2(date) {
        $('#fromDateCalendar').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);}


</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code, fix them and supply a fiddle !

Comment: cant able to understand your need correctly

Comment: update the code with no error but still the same problem

Comment: the problem is when i select a date in the first datpicker i change the min date for the second date picker ,just before the first datepicker close it show the second datepicker(instead of the first one) for a moment and then close it.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish. Take a look at this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QhYY3/) as an example (which is intentionally broken). After you select a date from the first `datepicker` it sets focus to the next one and the calendar opens and closes really quickly. Is this the issue you are having? The next `datepicker` closes too quickly? Or are you saying you want only one `datepicker` displayed on the page and only after a date is selected do you want to show the second `datepicker`? Or you want the second date to automatically populate?

Comment: after selecting a date in the  datepicker #1 i change the min date of the datepicker #2. i want the first datepicker to close without to see the datepicker #2 showing for a moment, like it does now. the datepicker #2 showes on datepicker #1 (not were it supposed to show).

Comment: i dont want the datepicker #2 to appears when i select a date in the datepicker #1

Comment: When I copy/paste your exact code in a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud3m4/) and select a date from the first datepicker, the calendar closes (as it should). The second calendar never opens. Because you're manually setting the value of the second datepicker to `09/01/2014` (or September 1, 2014), that value gets changed to `01/09/2014` (or January 9, 2014). That's happening because that is today's date and you're setting `maxDate: '0'` (in other words telling the `toDateCalendar` that the max date is the current day). You're not specifying a `dateFormat` which by default is `mm/dd/yy`

Answer (score 0):

to solve the problem of showing the #2 datepicker for a moment(in the place of the #1 datepicker) when i change the max date,
i call the ....datepicker('option', 'minDate', start) after the #1 datepicker close with setTimeout

```
 onSelect: function (date) {                                                  
                             setTimeout(function () {
                                 ....datepicker('option', 'minDate', start)
                             }, 300)
                        }....
```